# Can't install Google's v8 on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, v8

The thing is on ports and keeps saying it can't be maked:

```
make
===>  License check disabled, port has not defined LICENSE
===>  Found saved configuration for v8-3.10.4
===>  Extracting for v8-3.10.4
=> SHA256 Checksum OK for v8-3.10.4.tar.xz.
===>  Patching for v8-3.10.4
===>  Applying FreeBSD patches for v8-3.10.4
===>   v8-3.10.4 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/scons - found
===>   v8-3.10.4 depends on shared library: execinfo.1 - found
===>  Configuring for v8-3.10.4
===>  Building for v8-3.10.4
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
c++ -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -o obj/release/accessors.o -c -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Werror -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -m64 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -ansi -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -Isrc src/accessors.cc
c++ -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -o obj/release/allocation.o -c -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Werror -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -m64 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -ansi -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -Isrc src/allocation.cc
c++ -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -o obj/release/api.o -c -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Werror -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Woverloaded-virtual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -m64 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -ansi -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64 -DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT -Isrc -I/usr/local/include -Isrc src/api.cc
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
scons: *** [obj/release/api.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
*** Error code 2

Stop in /usr/ports/lang/v8.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/lang/v8.
```

VPS has 256 MiB, which is quite small, but from what I've googled, people have it running even on smaller amount of RAM.
Any tips?

Comment: People have it *running* with smaller amounts of RAM. *Compiling*, however, can require much more.

Comment: seems legit, but how would u run it without compiling it first?

Comment: By installing v8 as a compiled package, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is best practice, but you can install it like this:

`curl -O ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/packages/lang/v8-3.12.9.tbz && pkg_add -n v8-3.12.9.tbz`

Manually go the the `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/packages/lang/` to check the latest filename.

There are easier methods to install packages. Search in `ports/sysutils` or wait for the `pkgng` coming in fBSD 9.1